# android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing set flag in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

There is a new flag in Android Studio which is still experimental `android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing`. Unfortunately, it produces errors for us on Mac but works properly on Windows.

Can I set the flag programmatically in the build.gradle file, so I can set it to true on Windows and false otherwise?

If this is not possible, is it possible to set the flag in local.properties file? I don't want it to appear in changed files for git all the time when I set it to true on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Android Gradle plugin release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin), Google has explained as follows:

> **Improved incremental Java compilation when using annotation processors:** This update decreases build time by improving support for incremental Java compilation when using annotation processors.
>
> **Note:** This feature is compatible with Gradle 4.10.1 and higher, except
> Gradle 5.1 due to [Gradle issue 8194](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8194).

In your case:

> **For projects not using Kapt (Java-only projects):** If the annotation
> processors you use all support [incremental annotation processing](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:incremental_annotation_processing),
> incremental Java compilation is enabled by default. To monitor
> incremental annotation processor adoption, watch [Gradle issue 5277](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5277).
>
> If, however, one or more annotation processors do not support
> incremental builds, incremental Java compilation is not enabled.
> Instead, you can include the following flag in your `gradle.properties`
> file:
>
> ```
> android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true
> ```
>
> When you include this flag, the Android Gradle plugin executes the
> annotation processors in a separate task and allows the Java
> compilation task to run incrementally.

Comment: how is this answering my question? ^^

Comment: I know that you can set the flag in `gradle.properties`, but you can't set it dependent on the OS there (afaik). That's why I am asking whether it's possible to set it programmatically in `build.gradle` instead.